# Can I add custom skins to my Bedrock Server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I runa a dedicated Bedrock Server. I would like my players to be able to use my custom skin that I made for them. Is it possible? Maybe with resource packs?

Answer (score 0):

Just ask them to [upload the skin to their profiles and use it](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/how-to-change-skin-in-minecraft?r=US&IR=T) (go to Profile > Skins > [Custom] > [Select File].

Just make sure you've moved the skin into your shared storage (for iOS), internal storage (for Android), anywhere (for Win10) or a USB drive (for Xbox).

Comment: Umm.. This is not really what I'm looking for. I want my server to provide skins that are available for my players only. Also how would your solution work with consoles?